# Compilation issues in C

Tags: c, compilation, linker-errors

I have a problem when I compile my program and I don't know why. I think it's a library problem but I'm not sure. I searched on google but I couldn't solve the problem.

Command line:

```
clang `pkg-config --libs opencv `  main.o image_handle.o image_detection.o neural_network.o   -o main
```

This is my error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: neural_network.o: undefined reference to symbol 'exp@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

EDIT: my Makefile

```
#For the compilation
CC=clang

CPPFLAGS=`pkg-config --cflags opencv`
CFLAGS= -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c99 -O2
LDFLAGS=`pkg-config --libs opencv`

SRC= main.c image_handle.c image_detection.c neural_network.c
OBJ= ${SRC:.c=.o}

all: main clean

main: ${OBJ}

clean:
    rm -f *~ *.o

#END
```

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: @onegrx: how would that help?

Comment: My code is quite long. But it compiles on my co-worker's computer so I don't think that the code will help you. The error message started to appear when we started to use <math.h>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols:
                                 DSO missing from command line
```

That's the linker telling you it sort of found the symbol it was looking for, but not in a library you asked it to link with. So you should add that library to your command line. The flag for `libm` is `-lm`

```
clang main.o image_handle.o image_detection.o neural_network.o \
       `pkg-config --libs opencv ` -lm -o main
```

(You put the libraries after the objects that require them on the command line.)

Comment: I have tried to add the -lm flag on the CFLAGS, but nothing changed. I have added my makefile to my question.

Comment: End of CLAGS is not the right place. End of LDFLAGS should be. If it still doesn't work, post your edited makefile and the updated, exact, compiler output.

Answer (score 0):

The order of arguments when linking is important -- you need to list libraries AFTER object files.  Try:

```
clang main.o image_handle.o image_detection.o neural_network.o   -o main `pkg-config --libs opencv `
```